# How can I leave the MS-DOS editor?

Tags: windows, text-editors

How can I exit the MS-DOS editor, the editor which comes up if I type `edit` at a Windows prompt? The help available from F1 does not tell me this.

Comment: Wow, old school.  I haven't seen the DOS editor in...close to 10 years now?  Since i got rid of 98SE, anyway.

Comment: one way to leave edit.com is to use notepad ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `F1` Help file of edit.com did not explain about usage of `Alt` key.

Other than doing `Alt+F, X` to get `File > Exit` command, you can press `Alt` key then use the cursor keys to navigate edit.com menu system.

The (possibly) expected function of using the mouse to click on the `File` command does not work by default. This is because the DOS Window properties have "Edit Options" enabled for "QuickEdit Mode" and "Insert Mode". Click on the top left of the DOS Window then "Properties", and then disable those two "Edit Options", and you will be able to use the mouse to execute commands on the `edit.com` menu bar.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest turning off quickedit mode or insert mode. they're too useful outside of edit.com  But As to not being able to click, well, keyboard is fine, I always used ALT-F then UP then ENTER to exit. Though as you say, ALT+F,X will do fine.  You don't get the gratifying old DOS edit.com big yellow cursor anyway..

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried File -> Exit (alt+f, x)?

Answer (score 1):

You can exit `EDIT` by pressing 
`alt` `ENTER`  `uparrow` `ENTER`

Which will perform "File -> Exit -> Confirm"

It is also the same fingering to arpeggiate a major chord on a piano in a triangle-wave fashion.  Cheers and much love on this nostalgic post.